# How to skip focus on hidden group of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

Element or group of elements that are hidden with `display: none;` are skipped from keyboard focus (tab key) for accessibility reasons. When element turns visible it becomes accessible again, which is great.

Currently I'm using `opacity` and `right` position in order to create CSS transition. Those styles do not make element skipped from keyboard focus, which is what I want to achieve.

I would like to avoid adding `tabindex="-1"` to each of those inner elements if possible.

```
.element {
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  &.is-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 100px;
  }
}
```

I would like to have a way to hide/show element with transition, while keeping it skipped from keyboard focus until it's hidden.

Comment: if you are working with accessibility, is recommended add  'aria-hidden="true"' attribute. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria/hiding-and-updating-content

Comment: And I am, but that attribute doesn't make it excluded from keyboard focus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution is to add `visibility: hidden` to the hidden elements `CSS`, backing to `visibility: visible` when they're not hidden.

Because, like `display: none`, it ignores the `tabbing`, since the element no longer has visibility in the document, but the transition effect still happens.

Like this:

```
.element {
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  &.is-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    right: 100px;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for! Not sure why I didn't try with visibility :D